# SQL SUBSTRING from ntext field only text before and after

Tags: sql-server, substring

I have a column in a table that is ntext and contains multiple lines of text. example below. What I need is to have only this line "This suggests the stenosis is moderate" in the results of the query. I already have a substring in the select statement that removed all of the text before the line I want to be in the results, but I am not sure what to add to it to remove everything that follows it.

*this is the text I am working with, it could differ in content, but the line I need will always be present*

There is mild aortic regurgitation. 
Aortic valvular stenosis is present. 
Peak gradient is 29 mmHg, mean gradient is 17 mmHg and the orifice is 1.2 cm2 (+/- 0.15cm2) by continuity equation (LVOTd = 1.9 cm, V1 = 1.1 m/s, V2 = 2.7 m/s). 
**This suggests the stenosis is moderate** from the continuity equation. 
This stenotic aortic valve calcification is moderate-severe. 
The peak aortic gradient was obtained from the axillary window.
LVOT size revised up to 1.9 cm - LVOT measured on prior study as well.

*This is the substring I have in the select statement*

```
    `SUBSTRING(CAST(s.av_summary as NVARCHAR(MAX)), CHARINDEX('This suggests 
    the stenosis', CAST(s.av_summary as NVARCHAR(MAX))) , 
    LEN(CAST(s.av_summary as NVARCHAR(MAX)))) as AV_Summary`
```

Comment: Are you aware that the warning at the top of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) has appeared, in some form or other, ever since *2005*. It's *beyond* time to have eliminated `ntext` from your DB.

Comment: I wish I could, this is a database for an application that I maintain. I do not have the power to tell the company that they need to change the format of their database. Although I have spoke my mind about it several times to the company:)

Comment: since you are removing the text other than 'This suggests the stenosis is moderate ' all you have to do is output that text 'This suggests the stenosis is moderate ' if the string contains it  - so I'm puzzled by why you are trying to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , **length** )

so take needed count of symbols:

```
SUBSTRING (
CAST(s.av_summary as NVARCHAR(MAX))
,CHARINDEX('This suggests the stenosis', CAST(s.av_summary as NVARCHAR(MAX)))
,LEN('This suggests the stenosis')
) as AV_Summary
```

Comment: Perfect! that is exactly what I needed to do. Thank you much sir!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('This suggests the stenosis', CAST(s.av_summary as NVARCHAR(MAX))) > 0 
            THEN 'This suggests the stenosis' 
            END AS txt
```